# about arrays in c++ and shifting the elements

Tags: c++

I was practicing my c++ skills and I went into a question.
I have an array of 20 elements, 10 of them were declared before EX: list[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].
My job was to write a function that inserts the last elements
but after each element of the existing ones for EX: list[1, 0, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5 ...] etc.

what I did is declaring the last 10 elements to 0

```
void insertNum(int list[], int &count){

  srand(time(NULL));
  count = 20;
  int temp = 0;
    int i, j, min;
  for (int i = 10; i < count; i++) {
        list[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

but I couldn't find the complete solution and it's killing me.
any ideas about how to do it?

this the whole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


const int CAP = 20;
void buildList(int[], int &count);
void printList(int[], int count);


void insertNum(int list[], int &count);


int main(){
    
    int list[CAP], count = 0;
    buildList(list, count);
    cout << "Original List!" << endl;
    printList(list, count);
    insertNum(list, count);
    cout << "List after inserts!" << endl;
    printList(list, count);
    return 0;
}


void buildList(int list[], int &count){
    srand(time(NULL));
    count = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}


void printList(int list[], int count){
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }
}


void insertNum(int list[], int &count){

}
```

Comment: Use [`std::vector<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::rotate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to do that. No need to invent that again. Knowing what to use from the standard library, and how, is what makes up real c++ programming skills.

Comment: yeah about that the question was not to use any functions only loops

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` is not needed as nothing in your question talks about random. Also if you did need random numbers and were forced to use `rand()` it's usually best to call that 1 time in `int main()` then never call it again unless you have a some need to reseed on a key press or something like that.

Comment: i'm gonna post the whole code so u can get the whole idea

Comment: Discuss with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what effect `int list[CAP], count = 0;` will have on the number of iterations of the loop in `buildList`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question fully, But if I am right you want to create a function that inserts one element after each element of an existing array. This might be what you are looking for. If not please rephrase the problem.

```
    srand(time(NULL)); // need to do in main function only.
    int oldArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int finalArray[20] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int newElement = rand()%11+10; //random number between 10 to 20. Figure out what and from where new element will come from
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            finalArray[i] = oldArray[i / 2];
        else
            finalArray[i] = newElement;
    }
```